# 2003 Mazda Tribute Rear Wiper Fluid

Tags: mazda, windshield-wipers

My rear wiper fluid sprayer isn't working.  Is there a separate fluid tank for the rear wiper?  Is there a separate pump for this that could be broken?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears from what I've been reading, there is only one fluid reservoir, which is in the front. There is, I believe a separate pump for the back end. If you are turning the switch and not hearing anything, most likely the pump is not functioning. If you turn the switch and nothing is coming out, I read where one person said to just hold it on for a longer period (60-120 seconds) of time to refill the line coming from the front. If that doesn't work you probably have a clogged line. Also, stupid thing to say, but ensure your front reservoir is full.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, get a pin and insert it in the tiny hole of the wiper.. Dust or something else might have blocked the water from coming out.. This has worked for me before